# Intercalate SQL results

Tags: sql

So, I have the following UC to solve, but I still didn't figure out. The way I have it today is a total mess: bring the result from database and progragammatically order it.

Long story short, what I'm looking for is order by process priority, but for each pair of High priorities, I need to show a low priority process:

[image: TABLE]

Given a simple table Process

```
CREATE TABLE PROCESS (
   PROCESS_ID INTEGER,
   DESCRIPTION VARCHAR,
   PRIORITY INTEGER
);
```

And here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT
    PROCESS_ID,
    DESCRIPTION,
    PRIORITY
FROM 
    PROCESS
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRIORITY order by p.ID_PROCESSO)
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    PROCESS_ID,
    DESCRIPTION,
    PRIORITY,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRIORITY order by p.ID_PROCESSO) as RN
  FROM 
    PROCESS) 
-- I don't know what to put here to order..
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

### Edit

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d75134)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Remember that SQL tables are unordered, so columns specifying the ordering are needed.

Comment: @GabrielCâmara could you share some sample data and the result you want to get for it? I'm afraid the requirement still isn't crystal clear (to me, at least)

Comment: @Mureinik, the table picture is the best I could do for now, let me know if it's enough, please. Thanks

Comment: SQFiddle has been broken for Oracle from quite a while now. But Postgres is working.

Comment: You say " for each High priority, I need to show a low priority process:" but you example shows two High priorities, then a low, then two high, then a low. Can you explain better how are sorting?

Comment: @JNevill, thanks, I meant for each pair of high priorities

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but here's my two cents:

```
create table rules (
  priority integer,
  quantity integer
);

insert into rules values (0, 2), (1, 1);
```

Store your rules (or whatever you call'em) in a second table.

```
with t as (
  select
    row_number() over(partition by p.priority order by p.id) - 1 zero_based_sequence_no,
    p.*
  from process p
)
select
  t.id,
  t.description,
  case t.priority when 0 then 'HIGH' else 'LOW' end
from t
join rules r
  on r.priority = t.priority
order by t.zero_based_sequence_no / r.quantity, t.priority;
```

After that, extend your query so you now have **n** groups with a *sequence number*. For this instance, you have 2 different sequences, 0-3 for high priority records and 0-1 for the low ones. After that just join the rules and order them according to the quotient produced by the division of the zero based sequence number and the quantity of items of the same priority you want ordered. Include the priority in the ORDER BY clause and you will get what you need (this works fine due to how priority identifiers were assigned).

Comment: Let me first thank you for answering. It doesn't matter if u're late or not. That may be helpful for others!